# Would uninstalling old drivers from Device Manager solve this USB not recognised message?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usb-c

My current computer is a Dell Latitude 7320 but recently the left port keeps giving me USB not recognised message whenever a plug anything into it. I've tried the usual of uninstalling the driver from Device Manager, updating Windows and Dell drivers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Look in Device Manager and see if there are USB Drivers.  If no drivers for your USB, your left port may have a Hardware Issue. Look also for Red or Yellow icons next to USB.

Comment: I've seen old ports with issues like bent pins that cause weird "device error" problems or ports that simply cause a computer to power down when something is plugged in. Over time dry joints in the soldering of the motherboard could also cause odd issues. As John says, a fault with the physical port is potentially an issue.

Comment: Specific to your question.. not very likely.  You probably have a hardware error.  Are you able to boot anything using that port before the machine has even loaded an OS (as in LinuxLive disk)?  I am doubting it but that will give you an absolute answer.

Comment: No; What you describe most certainly a hardware problem.

Comment: Did you recently perform a fresh install of the OS without an image backup?  Also, want to point out you may need to specify the driver (not just install) by choosing "have disk" to manually select a driver besides what the systems believes to be the correct one.  You can remove the old/incorrect drivers using `rapr.exe`, but in my experience conflicts mostly occur when OEM drivers differ from `wuauclt.exe` drivers.